# Audio [MediaPlayer] is not working for my Piano Apps

Tags: android

Now, I try to built a piano application. The concept is to play a sound I must touch a button. Now, I have 7 button and for each button play a sound file. Here is the code.

```
package com.andikurnia.piano;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class IsaronActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    ImageView button1;
    ImageView button2;
    ImageView button3;
    ImageView button4;
    ImageView button5;
    ImageView button6;
    ImageView button7;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final MediaPlayer sound_6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.saron_6);
        final MediaPlayer sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.saron1);
        final MediaPlayer sound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.saron2);
        final MediaPlayer sound3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.saron3);
        final MediaPlayer sound5 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.saron5);
        final MediaPlayer sound6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.saron6);
        final MediaPlayer sound11 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.saron11);

        button1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.one);
        button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent touchEvent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(sound_6.isPlaying()){
                    sound_6.stop();
                    sound_6.seekTo(0);
                }else{
                    sound6.start();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        button2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.two);
        button2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View two, MotionEvent touchEvent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(sound1.isPlaying()){
                    sound1.stop();
                    sound1.seekTo(0);
                }else{
                    sound1.start();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        button3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.three);
        button3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View three, MotionEvent touchEvent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(sound2.isPlaying()){
                    sound2.stop();
                    sound2.seekTo(0);
                }else{
                    sound2.start();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        button4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.four);
        button4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View four, MotionEvent touchEvent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(sound3.isPlaying()){
                    sound3.stop();
                    sound3.seekTo(0);
                }else{
                    sound3.start();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        button5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.five);
        button5.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View five, MotionEvent touchEvent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(sound5.isPlaying()){
                    sound5.stop();
                    sound5.seekTo(0);
                }else{
                    sound5.start();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        button6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.six);
        button6.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View six, MotionEvent touchEvent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(sound6.isPlaying()){
                    sound6.stop();
                    sound6.seekTo(0);
                }else{
                    sound6.start();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        button7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        button7.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View seven, MotionEvent touchEvent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(sound11.isPlaying()){
                    sound11.stop();
                    sound11.seekTo(0);
                }else{
                    sound11.start();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is when I touch a button (for example button1) the audio file called and play properly. But, when I move my finger to touch other buttons, The sound on that button just play half and when I back to button before, it can't play sound again. Anyone can help analyze my code..? :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to release the MediaPlayer instance after you are done with it..

A better way to implement this would be (This code might not be compilable.. but it should help you get started)

```
private MediaPlayer mp;
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent touchEvent) {
     switch(v.getId()) {
         case button1:
             if(null == mp){
                 mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.saron1);
             } else {
                 //mediaplayer is already created so release it
                 //you may also want to consider stopping it..
                 mp.release();
                 mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.saron1);                     
             }
             mp.start();
             break;
             //..
             //..
             //.. and so on
     }
}
```

Comment: so, It is not recommended to create more than one MediaPlayer in a program...? If that so, I must create an array to implement my buttons. Ok, I'll try it.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, I just started develop an android program. Thank you for your help. :)

I'm a blogger too, come to my place at (http://blog.andikurnia.com)